# Windows 2008 32bit. Having issue deleting files

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, clearcase, snapshot

I have an issue with deleting files from a command line.  I can delete the file just fine through the Windows interface but i need to be able to run a script and delete multiple files.  I am getting access denied and I am logged in as administrator. Any thoughts?

Here is the code

```
cd C:\views\IPGW_bld4_snap\direcpc
 @echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

      for /f "delims=" %%a in ('cleartool ls -r -view_only') do del /q "%%a"
  pause
```

Here is the output from cleartool ls -r -view_only

```
 c:\views\IPGW_bld4_snap\direcpc>cleartool ls -r -view_only
   .\noc\ipgateway\build\gen_html.vcproj
   .\noc\ipgateway\build\libfcgi.vcproj
   .\noc\ipgateway\build\libjson.vcproj
   .\noc\ipgateway\ipgw\fcgicmdinf.c
   .\noc\ipgateway\ipgw\fcgicmdinf.h
   .\noc\ipgateway\ipgw\genconfightml.h

   c:\views\IPGW_bld4_snap\direcpc>
```

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general OS tech support.

Comment: It is part of programming a batch file to clean out a snapshot view after an update.  here is the command ....... for /f "delims=" %%a in ('cleartool ls -r -view_only') do del /q "%%a".........I am getting access denied when i run the script but not when i delete the file manually from the gui.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a ClearCase snapshot view, you can find file in read-only by default.
As mentioned in "[Batch delete : Access is denied](https://superuser.com/a/365715/141)", try using `del /F /Q`

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('cleartool ls -r -view_only') do del /f /q "%%a"
```

You can couple that with "[How to delete empty folders using windows command prompt?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7831319/6309)":

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%d in (`"dir /ad/b/s | sort /R"`) do rd "%%d"
```

That way, no empty folder is left behind after removing private files.

Comment: @user4067896 Do you mean this answer your question? (as in http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: That got me a lot farther.  Now there are several directories and sub directories that are not getting deleted.  I am not getting an error message either and i added /s

Comment: for /f "delims=" %%a in ('cleartool ls -r -view_only') do del /s /f /q "%%a"

Comment: @user4067896 do you mean the files are removed, but that leave empty folders?

Comment: exactly - I need these as clean as possible.  We are building several versions past, current, and future and when they see stuff from the future they freak.  Trying to avoid maintaining 50+ different build scripts.

Comment: @user4067896 maybe a second command like http://stackoverflow.com/a/7831319/6309 could help?

Comment: Thank you so much that was it.  It needed to be an rd instead of del.  I have both commands in now and it completely cleans the snapshot view.  thanks.

Comment: @user4067896 Great! I have edited my answer to include that command. Don't forget to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer for this question and the previous ones.

Comment: @user4067896 it does work for this question. Check your previous questions as well.