# Add 'Delete empty folders' to Windows context menu

Tags: windows, contextmenu, directory

I'd like to add to context menu this [nice shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7831319/694360) that automatically deletes all empty folders and subfolders under the folder it is run from:

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%d in (`"dir /ad/b/s | sort /R"`) do rd "%%d"
```

To add such an item to (directories) context menu I should run a file with `reg` extension having a content similar to

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Delete empty folders]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Delete empty folders\Command]
@=for /f "usebackq delims=" %%d in (`"dir %1 /ad/b/s | sort /R"`) do rd "%%d"
```

but this one does not work. How should it be fixed to properly run the one liner shell script?

Comment: Put the code in a .bat file, put the bat file and an argument identifier in the reg key.

Comment: @Alex: Should be possible by calling `cmd /c` with the rest of the command line.

Comment: @Joey Using `@="cmd /c for /f \"usebackq delims=\" %%d in (\`\"dir %1 /ad/b/s | sort /R\"\`) do rd \"%%d\""` I managed to delete empty folders in some positions but not everywhere, can you elaborate it?

Comment: @Joey Looks like you also have to enclose argument `%1` in double quotes, i.e. `\"%1\"`.

Answer (score 8):

Thanks to Joey comment I was able to find the following solution.

Step 1: create a file with `reg` extension (like for example `add_delete_empty_folders_to_context_menu.reg`) and put the following lines inside it:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Delete empty folders]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Delete empty folders\Command]
@="cmd /c for /f \"usebackq delims=\" %%d in (`\"dir \"%1\" /ad/b/s | sort /R\"`) do rd \"%%d\""
```

Step 2: double click on your `reg` file and give all the needed confirmations.

Now you have a handy `Delete empty folders` command in your context menu, popping up when you right-click on a directory. This works for me on Windows 7 and Windows 10.

Avoid abuse of this functionality, some softwares need their empty folders to work properly.

**Follow up**

If you experience trouble (as Enora, see below) you can try to use the following line in the `reg` file, in place of the original one:

```
@="cmd.exe /K for /f \"usebackq delims=\" %%d in (`\"dir \"%V\" /ad/b/s | sort /R\"`) do rd \"%%~d\""
```

I actually don't know if this version is more robust, I just report here the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34659731/694360) found by Enora for her case.

Comment: This works nicely. Could you also include version that adds some sort of icon to this option in the context menu?

Comment: @TMRW Sorry, this is beyond my knowledge. Maybe someone else will be able to help for that.

Comment: Np. I think i can do this myself with a bit of research.

Comment: @TMRW If you post here a solution on how to add an icon I'll be glad to use it and upvote it.

Comment: The one liner shell script doesn't work on my windows 7. I did step 1 and step 2 and I have  the "Delete empty folders" in my context menu but when I select this, a cmd windows open and I get this error: \.. was unexpected at this time. Any idea where in  `@="cmd /c for /f \"usebackq delims=\" %%d in (`\"dir \"%1\" /ad/b/s | sort /R\"`) do rd \"%%d\""` is the problem?

Comment: This one `@="cmd /c for /f \"usebackq delims=\" %%d in (`\"dir %1 /ad/b/s | sort /R\"`) do rd \"%%d\""` is giving me the error The system cannot find the path specified

Comment: @Arone I don't see the needed backquote (also known as backtick) character ( ` ) in the string you report, be sure to type it. If you don't have it in your keyboard (as me), you can print it typing 96 while you press the left ALT key.

Comment: Thanks for you time @mmj. The( ` ) is in my code but it was considered as a mini-Markdown formatting for "code" by the comment of SO. I did a copy paste of your code, so I have exactly the same one as yours!

Comment: @Arone Then I don't know what could be wrong. In order to find out if your problem is reproducible try on different directories and disks, and try the procedure on another installation if you can. You can also create a `delete_empty_folders.bat` file containing the line `for /f "usebackq delims=" %%d in (\`"dir /ad/b/s | sort /R"\`) do rd "%%d"`, to be copied and run from the parent directory, and see if at least the original batch DOS works.

Comment: Thanks @mmj! The bat is working! It's strange that it's not working from the context menu. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I managed to get the context menu to work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34659731/error-was-unexpected-at-this-time

Comment: @mmj, it' done thanks for adding the link in your answer (it's actually her not his)

Answer (score -2):

*E ia ora na tatou*

Here is another way:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\MenuDelZem]
"MUIVerb"="Supprimer les dossiers vides"
"Icon"="imageres.dll,-89"
"ExtendedSubCommandsKey"="Directory\\ContextMenus\\MenuCmd"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\background\shell\MenuDelZem]
"MUIVerb"="Supprimer les dossiers vides"
"Icon"="imageres.dll,-89"
"ExtendedSubCommandsKey"="Directory\\ContextMenus\\MenuCmd"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\ContextMenus\MenuCmd\shell\open]
"MUIVerb"="Supprimez-les "
"Icon"="imageres.dll,-89"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\ContextMenus\MenuCmd\shell\open\command]
@="cmd /c ROBOCOPY . .  /S /MOVE"
```