# error "\.. was unexpected at this time"

Tags: cmd, windows-7, registry

I have created a .reg with this to add a `Delete empty folders` command in my context menu. When I right click on a folder, this should delete its empty child folders.

I have the "Delete empty folders" in my context menu but when I select this, a cmd windows open and I get this error: .. was unexpected at this time. 
Any idea why?

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Delete empty folders]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Delete empty folders\Command]
@="cmd /c for /f \"usebackq delims=\" %%d in (`\"dir \"%1\" /ad/b/s | sort /R\"`) do rd \"%%d\""
```

The code comes from @mmj ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34018590/add-delete-empty-folders-to-windows-context-menu/34025977?noredirect=1#comment57136936_34025977))

**Edit**: thanks to JosephZ help here is the solution:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Delete empty folders]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Delete empty folders\Command]
@="cmd.exe /K for /f \"usebackq delims=\" %%d in (`\"dir \"%V\" /ad/b/s | sort /R\"`) do rd \"%%~d\""
```

Comment: What if you use fully qualified `C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe` instead of `cmd`?

Comment: @JosefZ I replaced `@="cmd /c for /f` by `@="C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c for /f` but it's no changing anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't apprehend why your code fails. For debugging purposes: both next `.reg`s work:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\List all subfolders2]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\List all subfolders2\command]
@="cmd.exe /K for /f \"usebackq delims=\" %%d in (`\"dir \"%V\" /ad/b/s | sort /R\"`) do @echo \"%%~d\""
```

Changes made on your code:

- `cmd.exe` instead of `cmd`;
- `/K` switch to keep command prompt window open;
- `%V` instead of `%1` but work with `%1` as well;
- `@echo` instead of `rd` as I do not want to delete any directory even if empty (merely for debug);
- `%%~d` instead of `%%d`.

Another escaping approach:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\List all subfolders]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\List all subfolders\command]
@="cmd.exe /S /K \"for /f \"delims=\" %%d in ('dir \"%V\" /ad/b/s ^| sort /R') do @echo \"%%~d\"\""
```

Excerpted from `cmd /?`:

> If `/C` or `/K` is specified, then the remainder of the command line
>   after the switch is processed as a command line, where the following
>   logic is used to process quote (`"`) characters:
>
> 1. If all of the following conditions are met, then quote character on the command line are preserved:
>
>    - no `/S` switch
>    - exactly two quote characters
>    - no special characters between the two quote characters, where special is one of: `&<>()@^|`
>    - there are one or more whitespace characters between the two quote characters
>    - the string between the two quote characters is the name of an executable file.
> 2. Otherwise, old behavior is to see if the first character is a quote character and if so, strip the leading character and remove the
>      last quote character on the command line, preserving any text after
>      the last quote character.

**Edit**: the solution (suggested by the OP [Arone](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3154274/arone) time after time):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Delete empty folders]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Delete empty folders\Command]
@="cmd.exe /K for /f \"usebackq delims=\" %%d in (`\"dir \"%V\" /ad/b/s | sort /R\"`) do rd \"%%~d\""
```

Answer (score 0):

The dir command resolves to

```
`"dir "%1" /ad/b/s | sort /R"`
```

but should resolve to

```
`dir "%1" /ad/b/s | sort /R`
```

Thus it should be

```
 `dir \"%1\" /ad/b/s | sort /R`
```

Update: If you have a batch working, why not call it from the context menu?

Comment: Thanks thst! But now I am getting the error `: was unexpected at this time`. I don't see any `:` in my code though! A bat file with :  `for /f "usebackq delims=" %%d in (\`"dir /ad/b/s | sort /R"\`) do rd "%%d"` do work though. But I am trying to get the context menu to work.