# How to not create empty folders?

Tags: httrack

I try to download only images from a certain website, with saving original folder nesting structure, where images are located on the website's server.

In filter settings i setup file types to download like:

```
+www.example.com/*.gif
+www.example.com/*.jpg
+www.example.com/*.jpeg
+www.example.com/*.png
-www.example.com/*.html
```

And everything runs OK, but HTTrack crreats empty folders where HTML files should be. In result i have full folder structure of the website, where some folders are empty, and some contain images.

The question is: how could i avoid creating of empty folders? I want only folders, which contain images.

Comment: I didn't use your program, but there is a way how to delete only empty folders here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7831286/how-to-delete-empty-folders-using-windows-command-prompt

Comment: it could be a way, thanks,  will give a try