# How to use rsync instead of move in for loop in batch

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, rsync

In every subfolder in the path U:\0012* I create an example folder and move the files from appropriate subfolder to example folder.

```
FOR /d %%A IN (U:\0012\*) DO mkdir %%~A\example & move %%~A\*.* %%~A\example\
```

What I want to try is to use rsync command instead of move

```
 FOR /d %%A IN (U:\0012\*) DO 
C:\cygwin\bin\rsync.exe -av -h --progress --checksum "/cygdrive/U/0012/%%A/*.*/" "/cygdrive/U/0012/%%A/EXAMPLE/"
```

The script is closing itself with a syntax error. Is it possible to use rsync in for loop?

Comment: It seems to me based on what you've included in your question that you cannot use rsync instead of move unless at least one of source or destination is not 'remote'. The answer is in your error message, please therefore explain what it is you need help with?

Comment: You are telling `rsync` to recurse into directories.  So you are creating a cyclical operation.  Your destination directory is also in your source path because you are using the `-r` option.  Which creates the cyclical operation.

Comment: So I've edit my question, both destinations aren't remote anymore

Comment: Perhaps this can help?
[Using rsync to move (not copy) files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43957/using-rsync-to-move-not-copy-files-between-directories)

Comment: whats the error you getting?

Comment: @CarlAlex No, the link is not related, please read the question again, especially around the `batch-file` tag and obvious batch related code.

Comment: @OlegNekhayenko You state _"The script is closing itself with a syntax error"_ but you do not provide the error. Please edit your question and provide the syntax error, this way it is much easier for us to determine what is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are having a clash of *"Windows World"* and "*Unix World*".

What you are trying with `rsync`, which is natural Unix tool, is to copy using a batch file path and put it into rsync path.  This will not work.

I'll dissect your code:

In this part you are still in the "Windows world" you are using `FOR` to loop via the `U:\0012\*` path in a windows way `FOR /d %%A IN (U:\0012\*) DO`.

You have tried to "help" `rsync` with unix style path `/cygdrive/U/0012/`, but the variable `%%A` contains the windows style path!

```
C:\cygwin\bin\rsync.exe -av -h --progress --checksum "/cygdrive/U/0012/%%A/*.*/" "/cygdrive/U/0012/%%A/EXAMPLE/"
```

The error you are getting is probably something like:

> The source and destination cannot both be remote. rsync error: syntax
>   or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1292) [Receiver=3.1.2]

How to solve such an error?

First is to say I'm using [MSYS](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/msys) environment for linux tools.  I have tested it on my local files.

In *batch files* you could do it the following way:

```
@echo off
FOR /d %%A IN (U:\0012\*) DO (
    SET "copy_path=%%A"
    C:\msys64\usr\bin\cygpath.exe -u %copy_path% > tmp_file.tmp
    SET /P unix_path=<tmp_file.tmp
    DEL tmp_file.tmp
    ECHO "%unix_path%"
    C:\msys64\usr\bin\rsync.exe -av -h --progress --checksum --remove-source-files "%unix_path%" "%unix_path%/EXAMPLE/"
    )
)
```

The script takes the Window path `C:\prg\PowerShell\test\SO\test1\*` and then it uses a `cygpath.exe` to convert the path to a unix style path and saves it to temporary file (`tmp_file.tmp`).  Then it reads from temporary file the path into the unix variable `%unix_path%` which is then used in the `rsync.exe`.

Note: As somebody already linked how to move file with rsync.  I'll just state the option.  You have to add `--remove-source-files`, which deletes files after transfer.

### ** Edit **

- I think I now understand what you mean.  Now `rsync` should really behave like move.  Only difference is that if directory `example` exists it is copied with the file. (if it does not it is created and files moved there) - I think that was original intentions when looking at `mkdir && move`.

What I have done?

`ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` to correctly read the variables from file (before it was only the last read)

`"!unix_path!/"` the last backslash is really important for rsync to behave correctly.

I have tested the script on my computer and for me it works as it should.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

FOR /D %%A IN (C:\prg\t\*) DO (
    ECHO %%A
    SET "copy_path=%%A"
    C:\msys64\usr\bin\cygpath.exe -u !copy_path! > tmp_file.tmp
    SET /P unix_path=<tmp_file.tmp
    DEL tmp_file.tmp
    ECHO "!unix_path!"

    ECHO C:\msys64\usr\bin\rsync.exe -av --progress --checksum --remove-source-files "!unix_path!/" "!unix_path!/example/"
    C:\msys64\usr\bin\rsync.exe -av --progress --checksum --remove-source-files "!unix_path!/" "!unix_path!/example/"
)
```

### ** Second Edit ** Empty directories are not deleted with rsync

I do not recommend using `--remove-files` && `--delete` options during one operation due to the fact the rsync can fail.  You can read more here [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/676671/rsync-does-not-delete-source-directories) or [unix stack exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78375/move-files-and-delete-directories-with-rsync) or even [server fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/384110/how-to-delete-empty-source-directories-when-moving-folders-with-rsync).

I would simply go with already written solution: [How to delete empty folders using windows command prompt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7831286/how-to-delete-empty-folders-using-windows-command-prompt) (I'm talking the solution (all credits to author) that takes in also directories with spaces):

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%d in (`"dir /ad/b/s | sort /R"`) do rd "%%d"
```

The final script would then look like this:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

FOR /D %%A IN (C:\prg\t\*) DO (
    ECHO %%A
    SET "copy_path=%%A"
    C:\msys64\usr\bin\cygpath.exe -u !copy_path! > tmp_file.tmp
    SET /P unix_path=<tmp_file.tmp
    DEL tmp_file.tmp
    ECHO "!unix_path!"

    ECHO C:\msys64\usr\bin\rsync.exe -av --progress --checksum --remove-source-files "!unix_path!/" "!unix_path!/example/"
    C:\msys64\usr\bin\rsync.exe -av --progress --checksum --remove-source-files "!unix_path!/" "!unix_path!/example/"
)
REM To delete empty directories - the windows way
REM save current directory to stack
pushd 

cd C:\prg\t
REM Will delete all empty directories (subdirectories) at current path
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%d in (`"dir /ad/b/s | sort /R"`) do rd "%%d"

REM return to saved directory
popd
```

Comment: I've tested your solution and the result was that all files in subfolders were deleted, only subfolders left the same

Comment: @OlegNekhayenko I don't understand your comment. "that all files in subfolders were deleted, only subfolders left the same".  How can be something deleted and left the same at the same time?

Comment: @OlegNekhayenko see my edit.  Now the script works as it should.

Comment: Thanks!! It's exactly what I needed. The only problem that the command "remove source files" leaves  a folder after removing the files which were inside.

Comment: @OlegNekhayenko Great! Since rsync does not support directly deleting commands I'll edit the post with more info.  Please don't forget to accept and upvote for the answer - https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score -2):

rsync can run inside the for loop. Below is the sample code for moving all files from a directory to "EXAMPLE" directory in same directory.

`#!/bin/sh
for d in ~/Desktop/a/*; do
rsync -rav -h --progress --checksum $d/*.* $d/EXAMPLE/ 
done`

Save the above in a .sh file and run the file. Here the above code will go through all subdirectories in ~/Desktop/a/ directory and will create EXAMPLE directory in each subdirectory and copy all files to EXAMPLE directory.

Comment: How is this connected to batch files and running the rsync tool from within?

Comment: Oh ok, I didn't see the batch-file tag.